# Comparison of custom data type with parameters

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, algebraic-data-types, do-notation

I am learning Haskell and trying to implement this program. I have a custom data type

```
data CalculatorInput 
    = Exit 
    | Error String 
    | Operator (Int -> Int -> Int)
    | Number Int
```

then I have a method `getInput` which returns a value of this type.

Now i am confused how to dispatch on values of this type. I have a method

```
simpleCalculator :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> IO ()
simpleCalculator ans op =  do
    input <- getInput   -- here i got the type as result
    if input == Exit then return()
    else if input == Number x then ans = ans op x; print ans
    else simpleCalculator ans op
```

I want to know whether the input is a `Number x`

I tried to use `case` as well:

```
simpleCalculator :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> IO ()
simpleCalculator ans op =  do
    input <- getInput   -- here i got the type as result
    --case input of
    --  Exit -> return ()
    --  Error x -> print x
    --  Number n -> ans = ans op x; print ans  -- getting error here, multiple statement not possible
    --  _ -> simpleCalculator ans op
```

I tried to create instance of `Eq` as well

```
instance Eq CalculatorInput where
    (==) Exit Exit = True
    (==) (Number x) (Number y) = x == y
    (==) _ _ = False
```

How can I compare custom data types with parameters or have multiple statements in a `case` branch?

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid. it didn't work. I tried. and i also notice it goes to inifnite loop on let ans = op ans n

Comment: @WaqarAhmedm `let ans = op ans n` -- This *recursively* defines `ans` in terms of itself.  You need to use a new name, in this case we often use a prime `'`: `let ans' = op ans n`

Comment: @luqui..i got it..thanks. one more question, why it is consider good not to return value from simpleCalculator method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost on the right track with your non-working code:

```
simpleCalculator :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> IO ()
simpleCalculator ans op =  do
    input <- getInput   -- here i got the type as result
    case input of
      Exit -> return ()
      Error x -> print x
      Number n -> ans = ans op x; print ans
      _ -> simpleCalculator ans op
```

You can nest `do` notations allowing you to write the following correct program:

```
simpleCalculator :: Int -> (Int -> Int -> Int) -> IO ()
simpleCalculator ans op =  do
    input <- getInput   -- here i got the type as result
    case input of
      Exit -> return ()
      Error x -> print x
      Number n -> do
        let theAns = ans op x
        print theAns
      _ -> simpleCalculator ans op
```

As for the `Eq` instance, you can let the compiler do the work for you by using [derivation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Classes_and_types#Deriving), i.e. writing

```
data CalculatorInput 
    = Exit 
    | Error String 
    | Operator (Int -> Int -> Int)
    | Number Int
    deriving Eq
```

Comment: Hi cactus, i tried this same logic yesterday and it worked. but i am confused, if i use ans = ans op x. it goes to infinite loop. can you please tell me why it is happening.

Comment: That's because if you do `let ans = ans op x`, the `ans` on the right-hand side refers to the same `ans` being defined.

Comment: Thank you, i got it...one more question, why it is consider good not to return value from method such as in this case simpleCalculator method?

Answer (score 0):

Use `case`.

```
simpleCalculator ans op =  do
    input <- getInput   -- here i got the type as result
    case input of
        Exit -> return ()
        Number x -> print $ans `op` x
        _ -> simpleCalculator ans op
```

You cannot derive `Eq` for `CalculatorInput` because functions are not instances of `Eq`.

Comment: i am already doing like this. How to execute multiple statements in switch case?

Comment: See my code please. In Haskell you don't execute statements. They are stated, not executed.